# Javascript Platformer style movement

Tags: javascript

I was trying to do something new. Creating a complete javascript game without canvas. It was just going to be a simple Platformer game with squares of different sizes and colors for the Player, obstacles and so on. So far what i've found very challenging to do is the movement. I've found a way around most of the other issues but i cannot figure out how to achieve smooth Platformer style walking and jumping. My attempts have led to the player succeeding to move but always stopping to carry out another movement instead of performing both actions at the same time. For example: Right, Stop, Jump, Stop, Right, Stop, Jump. Here is the script i used (without the keys' actions). I am open to suggestions on how to create smooth Platformer style walking and jumping.

```
document.onkeydown = KeyPressed;


function KeyPressed(k) {

var LeftBtn = 37;

var RightBtn = 39;

var UpBtn = 38;

var DownBtn = 40;

 if (k.keyCode == LeftBtn) {
     // Left Arrow Actions
 }

 if (k.keyCode == RightBtn) {
     // Right Arrow Actions
 }

 if (k.keyCode == UpBtn) {
     // Up Arrow Actions
 }
 }
```

Comment: how do you animate your player?

Comment: I dont. The game should be VERY simple

Comment: Your player needs to store velocity as well as position, otherwise you can't have concurrent movements. Also make sure that your possible key combinations don't trigger [keyboard ghosting](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/mechanical-switch-keyboard,2955-6.html).

Answer (score 1):

Please look at the following approach.

I use `keydown` and `keyup` event handlers to record which keys are pressed and which are released. So we know if several keys are pressed simultaneously. And we use these records to perform corresponding actions within the separate function running in the `requestAnimationFrame` loop.

Hope it helps.

```js
var codes = {37:'left', 39:'right', 38:'up', 40:'down'},
    step = 3, // pixels per keypress
    keys = {left:0, right:0, up:0, down:0};

var c = document.getElementById('c');

requestAnimationFrame(move);
document.onkeydown = KeyPressed;
document.onkeyup = KeyReleased;

function KeyReleased(k) {keys[codes[k.keyCode]] = 0}
function KeyPressed(k) {keys[codes[k.keyCode]] = 1}

function move(t) {
  c.style.left = c.offsetLeft + step * (keys.right - keys.left) + 'px';
  c.style.top = c.offsetTop + step * (keys.down - keys.up) + 'px';
  requestAnimationFrame(move);
}
```

```css
html, body {overflow:hidden}
#c {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%; left: 10%;
  font:900 400%/1 sans-serif;
}
```

```html
Click here and use arrow keys to move.
<div id="c">+</div>
```